# Writing Min-Max scaler function

Tags: python, data-science

I want to write a function for calculating Min-Max scale in python that return a list.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def normalize(x):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        return [(x[i] - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))]
```

Then calling the function:

```
normalize(x):
```

results:

```
[0.0]
```

I was expecting the result to be:

```
[0.00, 0.33, 0.66, 1.00]
```

Comment: The code has other issues, but I want to note you should not call `min`/`max` like that in a loop.  Those only need to be calculated once and could turn an O(n) algorithm into O(n^2) code.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @shehan's solution:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def normalize(x):
    return [round((i - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)), 2) for i in x]

print(normalize(x))
```

gives you exactly what you wanted. The result is rounded up unlike other solutions (as that's what you wanted).

result:

```
[0.0, 0.33, 0.67, 1.0]
```

For loop version of the answer so that op could understand:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def normalize(x):
    # A list to store all calculated values
    a = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        a.append([(x[i] - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))])
        # Notice I didn't return here
    # Return the list here, outside the loop
    return a

print(normalize(x))
```

Comment: upvoted for proposing to round the result so the output is formatted; however it reduces the precision kept, and this could be premature.

Comment: @Ruturaj  thank you. I was wondering why my for loop is not giving the expected answer.

Comment: @G1124E notice that you are returning withing your first iteration (hence, you got only first value, i.e. `0.0`). Instead, you should calculate for all the values then return the whole list. I hope you understand.

Comment: No, not sure what mean. Would you please add a for loop version of the answer.

Comment: @G1124E I added the answer, so that you could understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
def normalize(x):
    return [(x[i] - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) for i in range(len(x))]
```

Comment: You can simplify this by removing index `i` and instead have the `for` return `x_i` directly. 
`return [(x_i - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) for x_i in x]`
Your implementation is also O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing by `max(x)`, then subtracting `min(x)`:

You are also recalculating `max(x)`, and `min(x)` repeatedly. You could do something like this instead:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def normalize(x):
    maxx, minx = max(x), min(x)
    max_minus_min = maxx - minx
    return [(elt - minx) / max_minus_min for elt in x]
```

You can round the results, as suggested by @ruturaj, if that is the precision you want to keep:

```
return [round((elt - minx) / max_minus_min, 2) for elt in x]
```

Comment: This is better.